# jquery each running with out waiting ajax status

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, each

The .each method in jquery does not wait until success ajax call.

```
$("img[name='statusIcon']").each(function () {
    var statusIcon = $(this);
    statusIcon.attr('src', 'images/spinner.gif'); //loading image will be here
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var HostName = $("#" + row + " td[name='Public']").attr("title");
    var Pass = $.trim($("#pass_word" + row).attr("realValue"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validate.php",
        data: "HostName=" + HostName + "&uName=root&Pass=" + Pass + "&localCounter=" + stepCounter,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            if (res == 0) {
                statusIcon.attr('src', 'images/tick-mark.jpg'); //success image will be here
            } else {
                statusIcon.attr('src', 'images/cross_icon.jpg'); //fail image will be here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the code [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarantrs/jYEDH/)!

.each is completed until my first ajax call responds, while it should loop for every ajax call.
When it finishes with the previous ajax call, continues the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an attempt without using async:false

```
function doSomething(array){
    if(array.length == 0){
        return;
    }
    var statusIcon = $(array.shift());
    statusIcon.attr('src', 'images/spinner.gif'); //loading image will be here
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var HostName = $("#" + row + " td[name='Public']").attr("title");
    var Pass = $.trim($("#pass_word" + row).attr("realValue"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validate.php",
        data: "HostName=" + HostName + "&uName=root&Pass=" + Pass + "&localCounter=" + stepCounter,
        success: function (res) {
            if (res == 0) {
                statusIcon.attr('src', 'images/tick-mark.jpg'); //success image will be here
            } else {
                statusIcon.attr('src', 'images/cross_icon.jpg'); //fail image will be here
            }
        }
    }).always(function(){
        doSomething(array)
    });
}
doSomething($("img[name='statusIcon']").get())
```